# Replacing already accepted build by app with new one on iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have an app, the first version i.e 1.0 that is already uploaded on iTunesConnect and has been accepted by Apple and is now waiting for the developer release.

I want to replace that with new build.

I tried uploading new version 1.1 on iTunesConnect by its now showing me the option to submit for review and its been more than 12 hours.

Shall I reject the 1.0 binary and replace it with new one ? shall I wait ?

If, Incase I will reject the 1.0 binary and try to upload a new build with same version, how much approx time Apple will take to review it ?

Comment: All apple review will take 2 to 14 days. So what is the issue you are facing for uploading version 1.1 ?

Comment: you need to click on submit for review then select appropriat option IDFA and that status will be change to waiting for reivew

Comment: If Apple has approved the 1.0 it is too late to developer reject it.

Comment: @MidhunMP I am uploaded the new versions on Testflight and I am not able to add a new version on AppStore. I think my previous version 1.0 is not live that why I am not able to add version 1.1.

Comment: @NitinGohel That submit for review showed up when I uploaded the previous 1.0 version. For 1.1, version its not showing up. Also, I am not able to add a new version on AppStore may be because previous 1.0 is approved and not made live.

Comment: @Paulw11 Reject binary is not showing up on browser. It showing up on the iTunesConnect iPhone App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way for you to go is to just wait for apple to approve your 1.1 App Version since once apple has approved your 1.0 version you can't developer reject it.

Currently apple is taking about **6 days** to approve apps as you can check on [this page that shows average review times](http://appreviewtimes.com).

Since you said that the submitting option is not showing up you need to click on *submit for review* and then select appropriat option for IDFA. Your apps' status should change to waiting for review.

*btw. If it was possible to developer reject your Version 1.0 it would not be faster then submitting Version 1.1*

***UPDATE:***

---

You might want to try to release Version 1 and then developer reject it. Then I think you should be able to submit the update to version 1.1. :) 


If not possibly you are able to change the build of version 1 and resubmit that.

Comment: The problem is the submit for review option is not showing up only.

Comment: Also, I am not able to add new release version for AppStore. What I am thinking is because Version 1.0 is not live that why the option is not coming up.

Comment: You might want to check the updated answer @GouravJamwal

Comment: I had too release the first version 1.0 and then the next version got enabled. Thanks

Comment: Would you consider marking the answer as solved. This would show that you are not needing any more help. :) @GouravJamwal an up vote would be appreciated too.